# How to prevent commands from stealing emacs windows?

Tags: emacs

I've been learning GNU Emacs on a Windows system for the last couple of months. One thing that really bugs me is having commands steal or close my windows. For example, when launching eshell it will occasionally put it another window rather than the current one. I also have an extension for VC for IBM's clearcase which also kills windows when I check-in/out files.

I would have thought that the ability to lock a window so that nothing can kill it or steal it would be a fairly desirable feature. Does Emacs come with this built-in? I have a feeling that it does but I am just lacking the terminology for it.

Any info would be appreciated.

Regards,

Elliot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [StickyWindows](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/StickyWindows).

Download [sticky-windows.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/sticky-windows.el)

put the following lines in your `.emacs` :

```
(require 'sticky-windows)
(global-set-key [(control x) (?0)] 'sticky-window-delete-window)
(global-set-key [(control x) (?1)] 'sticky-window-delete-other-windows)
(global-set-key [(control x) (?9)] 'sticky-window-keep-window-visible)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was after. Many thanks Jerome. Now I can compartmentalize my workspace and not have to worry about my buffers being killed or stolen.

Answer (score 3):

(info "(emacs) Force Same Window") describes what's going on generally.

Comment: In newer versions of the Emacs manual: (info "(emacs) Displaying Buffers")